# Test Activity with SurfaceView on it with Espresso

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, surfaceview, android-espresso

I am writing UI test with Espresso for application for making videocalls and I`ve faced such a problem that I have a CallActivity, which has two SurfaceViews on it (one for self-video and other for remote person video). These SurfaceViews selfupdate constantly, so Espresso thinks that UI is busy and waits for UI to become IDLE but it never happens and AppNotIdleException is thrown. Has somebody faced the same issue? Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Having the same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: @yonix I didn`t, unfortunately

Comment: For me it ended up being something else that was working hard on the main thread, the rendering of the SurfaceView wasn't an issue after all